# How to refresh website until server has response ? in Java?

Tags: java, http, browser, httpurlconnection, httpresponse

I try to entry a busy website but always get the busy server result(error 500).

And I would like to use java code to loop the website until I can entry the website but i only know how to get the response code don't know how to open it in browse.

How to open the website in the connection of HttpURLConnection in browse or is there any other way to open or loop the website until no error? Many thanks!!!

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;

public class test{
     public static String URL = "http://www.example.com/";
     public static void main (String args[]) throws Exception{

       int i =0;
       while(i==0){
       URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/");
       HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
       connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
       connection.connect();
       int code = connection.getResponseCode();
        if (code != 500){
              //how to open the no error website.
           }
       System.out.println(code);
     }
    }

   }
```

Comment: Side note: If the other end is a site you control, you might want to fix which result it's returning... 500 means a server error, it's 503 that signifies that a server is busy.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to open a website upon receiving the 200 HTTP Status, you can do something like below inside your if ... else statement :

```
   if (code == 200){
      //how to open the no error website.
      if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
           Desktop.getDesktop().browse(url.toURI()); //referring to the url connection already created
           System.exit(0);
       }
   }
```

Comment: but using the way to open the browse will been a new connection and the server response also will get error.

Comment: I have try to loop around 100 times to print out the response code only get once times connect successful. Too many user try to entry at that time.

Comment: I don't know which website you are referring but you don't have control over that as a client. You can only check the Response Code and wait until you get a HTTP 200.

Comment: I can get the HTTP 200 , but dont know how to open than connection .I would like to start a loop for open website and check the response code and close the website if any error .

Comment: In order to put that check, you can add a counter to track the number of attempts (or time based) and modify your if condition such as if (code == 200 && numberOfAttempts < 100){ ... }

Comment: OK, I try more different way to do that , thanks. I only want to buy a ticket on time, its so hard.

Comment: Are there any way to open the connection with that HttpURLConnection in browse like connection.open()?

Comment: Updated the answer to use the same connection you created.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167592/discussion-between-prabin-paudel-and-ricky-c).